# Unity: What does the green line gizmo signify?

Tags: unity, lighting

[image]

When I place a point light it shows this green gizmo that ends in the terrain.
What's the name of this gizmo?
What does it signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it’s just to show you what location “above” the terrain the object currently is, to help you place it accurately. Small objects are notoriously hard to place correctly in 3D, since it’s hard to tell if they are near or far.